# Comparing results of functions and put them as a matrix MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Let's say I am getting the execution time of two funcion in Matlab, I have a loop to get different measurements:

```
for i = 0: 100
    Start1   = tic;
    somefunction1;
    Total1   = toc(Start1);

    Start2   = tic;
    somefunction2;
    Total2   = toc(Start2);
end;
```

How would I get a mtarix with the results of times like:

```
iteration times1      times2
  1       someval1     someval1
  2       someval2     someval2
  3       someval3     someval2
 ...
```

Could they be inserted in another matrix? How?

**-----------------------------------EDIT**
***I have done the suggestion and it works:***

```
N = 100;
Total = zeros(N,2);
for i = 1: N
    Start1     = tic;
    %somefun1
    Total(i,1) = toc(Start1);
    Start2     = tic;
    %somefun2
    Total(i,2) = toc(Start2);
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine Total1 and Total2 into one matrix.

```
N = 100;
Total = zeros(N,2);
...
Total(i,1) = toc(Start1);
...
Total(i,2) = toc(Start2);
```

I would keep iteration as a separate vector:

```
iteration = 1:N;
```

Then you can plot the results, for example:

```
plot(iteration,Total)
```